# How to customize call() to send custom ether value?

Tags: solidity, ether, contract-invocation

I'm writing a contract & trying to implement a small fee for a feature when users trade NFTs & I'm getting errors everything I add a custom `uint256` the transaction completely fails as such.

```
eth_estimateGas
  Contract call:       <UnrecognizedContract>
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0xe6e340d132b5f46d1e472debcd681b2abc16e57e
  Value:               0 ETH

  Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Ether sent to address failed'
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xe6e340d132b5f46d1e472debcd681b2abc16e57e)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at EthModule._estimateGasAction (/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:429:7)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:139:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:116:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:188:20)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/jsonrpc/handler.ts:167:17)
```

Here is my function trying to send 250 wei for example to another address

```
function payFee(address payable _addr) external payable {
    // ...... other dapp function calls 
    (bool success,) = _addr.call{value: 250}("");
    require(success, "Ether sent to address failed");
    emit PaymentSent(success);
}
```

Yet when I call the same function with `msg.value` instead of a `uint256 of 250` then the function passes. What am I doing wrong here? Is it even possible to impose a fee like this in solidity?

Comment: Did your contract have ETH balance? Your code worked perfectly at my end.

Comment: I was making a mistake on the remix end, I kept forgetting to add `Value` of 250wei when sending the transaction, part of me thought it would come out automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should call the address.transfer or address.send member instead of address.call; On my personal experience I only use address.call when I want to call a function within an external contract, read more info about this [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types)

```
<address payable>.transfer(uint256 amount)
send given amount of Wei to Address, reverts on failure, forwards 2300 gas stipend, not adjustable

<address payable>.send(uint256 amount) returns (bool)
send given amount of Wei to Address, returns false on failure, forwards 2300 gas stipend, not adjustable

<address>.call(bytes memory) returns (bool, bytes memory)
issue low-level CALL with the given payload, returns success condition and return data, forwards all available gas, adjustable
```

If you want something cheaper on gas and utterly overkill in knowledge terms you could do this; more info in YUL [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/yul.html#evm-dialect)

```
function _transfer(address to, uint256 amount) internal {
    bool callStatus;
    assembly {
        callStatus := call(gas(), to, amount, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
    if (!callStatus) revert TransferFailed();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I've only went with `call()` since the docs where stating that `call()` should be the standard choice over `send()` or `transfer()` but I tried `send()` with a uint256 & the function passed :)

Comment: yeah ahah In my Yul snippet I'm actually just using the call as you did in your example :3 all of them are valid and technically the same